# loop to exclude values from list by condition fails

Tags: python

I encountered the following problem:
I have a list of numbers and a maximal value.
I want to exclude all values in num that are greater than the given max. I wrote two loops that should be able to do so:

```
num=[0.5,1,1.5,2]
max=0.5

for eachNum in num:
    if eachNum>max:
        num.remove(eachNum)

i=0
while i<len(num):
    if num[i]>max:
        num.pop(i)
    i=i+1
```

Both loops failed. They left the 1.5 in the list and I do not get why. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `num.pop(i)` It's a bad idea to mutate (change) an object as you are iterating through it.

Comment: try appending the elements that pass the criteria to a new list instead of removing ones that fail

Comment: dont modify your list while iterating it - simple as that. use list comp: `a = [x for x in [0.5,1.5,2] if x <= 0.5]` and keep what you want.

Comment: You should not edit the list while you iterate over it. When you do that, `item[2]` suddenly becomes `item[1]`, but you've already iterated past that index, so it skips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loops are failing because you are changing the list while iterating over it.

A great way to accomplish this would be to use `filter`:

```
num=[0.5,1,1.5,2]
max=0.5
less_than_max = list(filter(lambda x: x < max, num))
```

Check out the python documentation for more info: 
http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html